# Jpa Hibernate @Query annotation with filters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have an Angular based Application for Front End and Spring Boot for Back End.

My componaent had a variable that contains filters like that

```
search:any={ 
    name:'',
    surname:'',
    address:'',
    phone:'',
    city:''
  }
```

i pass it to my Api with Post Method like that:

```
getPeoplesByFilters(filter){
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/search", filter)
    .map (resp => resp.json())
  }
```

I receive this in my Spring Boot Controller by this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search", method= RequestMethod.POST )
     public Page<People> searchFilters(@RequestBody() People p, 
             @RequestParam(value="page", defaultValue="0") int page ,
             @RequestParam(value="size", defaultValue="5") int size){

        p.setName("%"+p.getName()+"%");
        p.setSurname("%"+p.getSurname()+"%");
        p.setAddress("%"+p.getAddress()+"%");
        p.setPhone("%"+p.getPhone()+"%");
        System.out.println(p.getName());
        return poepleRepository.searchFilters( p ,  new PageRequest(page, size));

     }
```

And in my Jpa Repository interface I have this query:

```
@Query("select p from poeple p where p.name like :#{#x.name} and p.surname like :#{#x.surname} and p.address like :#{#x.address} and p.phone like :#{#x.phone} and p.mobile like :#{#x.phone}")

public Page<People> searchFilters(@Param("x") People x, Pageable pageable);
```

But I don't have any result

I tried just with one field and i fill it in my front end App and it work
But when I fill just one field and let another empty i have zero result.

What's Wrong!

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the SQL query conditions are AND and not OR ?

Comment: Yes I want to concatenate the filters

Answer (score -1):

My previous experience shows that using specifications is best for your case. Because it is more extendable and understandable. You can write specification like below.

```
public class Spec{
    public static Specification<Person> filter(FilterParams filterParams) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            if(filterParams.getName()!=null){
                predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("name"),filterParams.getName()));
            }
            if(filterParams.getSurname()!=null){
                predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("surname"),filterParams.getSurname()));
            }
            ....
            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        };
    }
   }
}
```

Then you can use like below:

```
@Service
public TestService{
@Autowired
PersonRepository personRepository;

void test(){
 FilterParam filterParam = new FilterParam();
 filterParam.setName("test);
 ...
 personRepository.findAll(Spec.filter(filterParam));
 }

}
```